# How to create a cumulative column

Tags: r

I would like to create a column allowing me to identify how many individus i studied. In my dataset, i have different varieties with different plants. This column will be really helpful to create graph in function of time.

Example:

Varieties
Abelastone
Abelastone
Abelastone
Abelastone
Abelastone

ligne.rep
1
1
1
1
1

Cumulative.mâle
0
0
0
0
0

I would like to have:

Cumalative mâle
1
2
3
4
5

This is my new column:

```
X[,9]<-0

colnames(X)[9]<-"Cumulatif mâle"
```

So i would like in this column to have: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on until arriving at the number of plants per variety that I am studying. But I don't know how to do that.

I have already isolated varieties.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a complete example as requested at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  That should include input shown as the result of running dput, code attempt and expected output.

Comment: Also, the function `cumsum()` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes thanks you mister, have a good day